# jQuery: Selecting specific closest / sibling row above the current

Tags: jquery, selector, traversal, closest, siblings

What have to be changed to have the TD cells with class "img" also highlighted, when the mouse goes over C,D,E & F (Pic 1 is highlighted) and K & L (Pic 3 is highlighted) - not only over the "first row" where the "rowspan" is  defined (A,B,G,H & J)?

```
<table class="stripeMe" border="1">             
  <tr class="row1">                 
    <td rowspan="3" class="img">Pic 1</td>
    <td>- A -</td>
    <td>- B -</td>                 
  </tr>                  
  <tr>
    <td>- C -</td>
    <td>- D -</td>                 
  </tr>             
  <tr>
    <td>- E -</td>    
    <td>- F -</td>                 
  </tr>             
  <tr class="row1">                 
    <td rowspan="1" class="img">Pic 2</td>
    <td>- G -</td>    
    <td>- H -</td>                 
  </tr>          
  <tr class="row1">                 
    <td rowspan="2" class="img">Pic 3</td>       
    <td>- I -</td>    
    <td>- J -</td>                 
  </tr>                  
  <tr>      
    <td>- K -</td>    
    <td>- L -</td>                 
  </tr>             
</table>
```

CSS

```
tr.over td {
  background-color: #f70;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".stripeMe tr").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("over");}).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("over");});
});
```

Code example to try: http://jsfiddle.net/9krDS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stripeMe").delegate("td", "mouseover", function() {
     if($(this).closest("tr").hasClass("row1")){
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".img").addClass("over");
     } 
     else{
         var tr =  $(this).closest("tr");
         while(!tr.hasClass("row1")){
            tr =  tr.prev("tr");   
         }       
         tr.find(".img").addClass("over");                   
     }

 })
 .delegate("td", "mouseout", function(){
        $(this).closest(".stripeMe").find(".img").removeClass("over");
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not what I expect...
Look here, what is the result of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh2wh/

Maybe I was not so clear about what I want to achieve: I want on mouse over on all of the rows A..L to highlight also the corresponding Pic 1..3, as it does on the "first rows" (A,B,G,H & J)

Comment: @Billy - What is that you need exactly?

Comment: I was to fast before. My answer on your question is above, on my comment.

Comment: I checked in jsfiddle, my answer perfectly works as you had mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Billy - Please check my edited answer it works now as you expected [http://jsfiddle.net/Hh2wh/]

Comment: Great! This solves almost my problem. Almost, because it is not highlighting the complete row. I added my code after yours (as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/c85Ss/) and it works as expected!
Thank you!
But I thought it would be "easier" (more "elegant", something like that: ".closest(tr.row1 > td.img" or so...) to achieve that... But anyway, it works at the moment!

Comment: I am glad it helped you, can you please vote too for my answer :)

Comment: I will vote for your answer, as far es I can. At the moment, I have a to small "reputation"...